# Multiple Decoration Views added to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm creating a basic collection view layout which subclasses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. However, I'm noticing that there appear to be several decoration views stacked on top of one another.

Whenever the user selects an item in the last section, I'm adding a new section with the code below. It seems that whenever I execute this code, one additional copy of the decoration view is being added to each already existing section.

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    currentModelArrayIndex++;
    [collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentModelArrayIndex]];
    [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentModelArrayIndex-1]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:currentModelArrayIndex] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}];
```

I've corroborated this by giving my decoration views an `alpha` of `0.2f` and seeing them stack up.

[image]

I also performed a dump of the collection view hierarchy and saw 10 instances of `AFDecorationView` when I should only see 4:

```
   | <AFDecorationView: 0x719ee50; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 65; 768 208.125); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x719eec0>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0x71ad980; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 333.125; 768 203.281); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x71adb60>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0x71afc90; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 65; 768 208.125); layer = <CALayer: 0x71afd60>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd79ac30; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 596.406; 768 203.281); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xd79ad00>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd79cf20; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 333.125; 768 203.281); layer = <CALayer: 0xd79cff0>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd79dac0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 65; 768 208.125); layer = <CALayer: 0xd79a980>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd794fd0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 859.688; 768 225.938); layer = <CALayer: 0xd7950a0>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd7a1300; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 596.406; 768 203.281); layer = <CALayer: 0xd7a13d0>></CALayer:>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd7a35d0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 65; 768 208.125); layer = <CALayer: 0xd794470>>
   | <AFDecorationView: 0xd7a43e0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 333.125; 768 203.281); layer = <CALayer: 0xd7a44b0>>
```

I have tried looking at [another custom layout example](https://github.com/mpospese/IntroducingCollectionViews), but they seem to instantiate quite a few instances of their decoration views, too. Could this be a bug in `UICollecionView`? Or is it up to us to only add the decoration view layout attribute in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` once per section?

The decoration-related parts of custom layout look like the following.

```
@implementation AFCollectionViewFlowLayout

-(id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    [self registerClass:[AFDecorationView class] forDecorationViewOfKind:AFCollectionViewFlowLayoutBackgroundDecoration];

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Private Helper Methods

-(void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attributes
{
    //implemented
}

#pragma mark - Overridden Methods

#pragma mark Cell Layout

-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributesArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    NSMutableArray *newAttributesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesArray)
    {
        [self applyLayoutAttributes:attributes];

        if (attributes.indexPath.item == 0)
        {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *newAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:AFCollectionViewFlowLayoutBackgroundDecoration atIndexPath:attributes.indexPath];

            [newAttributesArray addObject:newAttributes];
        }
    }

    attributesArray = [attributesArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newAttributesArray];

    return attributesArray;
}

#pragma mark Decoration View Layout

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString *)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:decorationViewKind withIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([decorationViewKind isEqualToString:AFCollectionViewFlowLayoutBackgroundDecoration])
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *tallestCellAttributes;
        NSInteger numberOfCellsInSection = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfCellsInSection; i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:indexPath.section];

            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttribtes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];

            if (CGRectGetHeight(cellAttribtes.frame) > CGRectGetHeight(tallestCellAttributes.frame))
            {
                tallestCellAttributes = cellAttribtes;
            }
        }

        CGFloat decorationViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(tallestCellAttributes.frame) + self.headerReferenceSize.height;

        layoutAttributes.size = CGSizeMake([self collectionViewContentSize].width, decorationViewHeight);
        layoutAttributes.center = CGPointMake([self collectionViewContentSize].width / 2.0f, tallestCellAttributes.center.y);
        layoutAttributes.zIndex = -1;
    }

    return layoutAttributes;
}

@end
```

I only want one decoration view per section, so I'm adding the decoration view to the first section.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this, but I have 2 comments: (a) can you check and see how many times your `if (attributes.indexPath.item == 0) ` is true? Perhaps there are other views, like other supplementary views which are causing it to fire more than you expect? and (b) it seems a bit funny to use the presence of the row 0 cell in a given section to determine if you should include your decoration cell, since they (I assume) occupy different rects and so some calls to `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` should probably return one and not the other.

Comment: Also: does the behaviour change if you just use `reloadData` instead of doing your batch updating?

Comment: A while ago I struggled with a collection view problem too. After a lot of hours trying to fix it, I submitted a TSI. The Apple engineer told me that it was a bug. It seems to be quite buggy…

Comment: @JesseRusak Thanks for the suggestions - I will experiment to see if you're right. Can you suggest an alternative for for `indexPath.item == 0`? My decoration views are one per section. Thanks!

Comment: I've changed my check to `attributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategorySupplementaryView` and added logging to see if it's being added more than once, but it looks normal. I think GuidoH is right - this is just buggy.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, Ash. You could implement layoutAttributesForElementsInRect to get the number of sections from the dataSource, and then calculate which elements would be in the passed rect, generate those and return them. But if your code seems to be doing what you expect, I don't see why that would be any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `UICollectionView`. I've filed a [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2550401) with Apple.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right. I have a similar issue, in which decoration views of the wrong kind are being used after a content update, and existing ones not being removed. This isn't the only bug I reckon I've seen in UICollectionView either. Hopefully it will be sorted in the next release.

Comment: Having similar issues. UICollectionView is not production ready IMHO. Too many bugs, especially with decoration/supplementary views. Apple really dropped the ball with this one

Comment: Did you get a reply from apple about the bug? I have a similar issue with supplementary views stacking up - this time when i invalidateLayout. The extra views are never removed and this is causing real problems when my layout moves things around.

Comment: This has been resolved as of iOS[redacted] – no other recourse for now.

Comment: I'm experiencing this bug on iOS 8.1.3. In my case it happens if I set the `contentOffset` programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I was able to solve it by manually removing all decoration views in `prepareLayout` in my custom layout class (I do that right before I invoke `[super prepareLayout]`):

```
    // Iterate over all subviews to remove all decoration views 
    for (UIView *view in self.collectionView.subviews) 
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[DecorationView class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }
    [super prepareLayout];
```